# Proof that $a^x$ is the only solution of $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$

Tags: calculus, functions, exponential-function, functional-equations

Obviously $a^x$ is a solution of $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$. But how do I prove that it is the **only** solution of that functional equation (apart from $f(x)=0$ or $f(x)=1$)

Comment: $f(x)=0$, $f(x)=1$.

Comment: Is $f$ a function on real numbers? Complex numbers? Integers? Rational numbers? Natural numbers? Is it continuous?

Comment: There are lots of solutions that are not continuous: See [Cauchy functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation). Any solution $g$ of Cauchy's functional equation gives a solution $f(x)=e^{g(x)}$ of your equation.

Comment: $x$ can be an arbitrary complex number.

Comment: Is [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1548249/a-function-with-a-property-fxy-fxfy) a duplicate of your question?

Comment: @Axion004 It's a duplicate. Thanks for the link.

Comment: With $x=y$, we have $f(2x)=f^2(x)$ which shows that $f$ is non-negative. $f$ is also nonzero, otherwise if $f(y)=0$ for some $y$, then $f(x+y)=0$ and $f$ is the constant $0$. Then we can take the logarithm and $\log f(x+y)=\log f(x)+\log f(y)$ is the linearity condition.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy I'm not completely familiar with all the mathematics used within the article. Could you give me an example of such $g(x)$?