# Conditions for the identity f(a)f(b)=f(a+b) to hold

Tags: probability-distributions

If I have the identity

$$f(a)f(b)=f(a')f(b')$$

for a given normalized probability distribution $f$, and additionally the constraint

$$a+b = a'+b' = const.$$

for any suitable pairs of real numbers $a,b$ and $a',b'$, would this be sufficient to conclude that

$$f(a)f(b)=f(a+b)$$

or are there further conditions required?

I know that the latter relationship implies that $f$ is an exponential function, but I would like to know which conditions are mathematically required for this, and I can't quite see how this would follow from the two conditions alone I mentioned.

Comment: this is very vague.  What is $f$?  What does "suitable" mean?  What does this have to do with probability?

Comment: @lulu 
Well, $f$ is a probability distribution, and "suitable" pairs $a,b$ and $a′,b$′ means those that satisfy the constraint $a+b=a′+b′$

Comment: I suggest editing your post for clarity.   You don't, for instance, mention that $f$ is a probability distribution in the post.  If you have an example of a probability distribution with this property, you should include it.

Comment: If you have the condition $f(0)=1$ then $f(a)f(b)=f(a+b)f(0)=f(a+b)$.

Comment: @Shean But by the same token, the desired relation is false unless $f(0)=1$

Comment: @lulu I am trying to find some simple mathematical conditions sufficient for a function to be a normal (exponential) distribution. I know that $f(0)=1$ does it, but this is not something I can assume from the start, it should rather come out as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(a)f(b)=f(a+b)f(0)=f(a+b)\iff f(0)=1$$

Hence, $f(a)=c^a$ for some constant $c$ (see e.g. [A function with a property $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1548249/a-function-with-a-property-fxy-fxfy?noredirect=1&lq=1)).

Comment: Sorry, but how do you get to this equation "$f(a)f(b)=f(a+b)f(0)$"?

Comment: Let $a'=a+b$ and $b'=0$. Then $a+b=a'+b'$ satisfying your constraint.

Comment: and the second equal sign $=f(a+b)$?

Comment: But there are no functions of the form $x\mapsto c^x$ which integrate to $1$ over the entire real line.

Comment: @Thomas $f(0)=1$.

Comment: So $f(0)=1$ would be a further condition to have $f(a)f(b)=f(a+b)$, not something that follows from the other conditions mentioned? This is not really what I was looking for, but it would also be sufficient for me if I can rule out $f(0)=0$. From your above equation $f(0)=0$ would mean $f(a)f(b)=0$ so either $f(a)=0$ or $f(b)=0$ or both, which however would be impossible unless $f$ is identically zero. Would you agree?

Comment: @lulu $e^{-x^2}$ integrates to 1 over the real line (if suitably normalized), as does $e^{-x}$ for $x>0$.

Comment: $f(0)=1$ is a sufficient and necessary condition, thats the $\iff$ in my answer. If $f(0)$ you can show $f$ is identically equal to 0, yes. Also, $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ wouldn't work. Do you see why?

Comment: The equal sign in the equation $f(a+b)f(0)=f(a+b)$ I don't understand. You probably meant $f(a+b)f(0)\overset!=f(a+b)$, but this would mean enforcing the equation. I would like to *derive* it by means of the conditions/ constraints mentioned.      

I know what you mean regarding $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ . In this case just replace the $a$ and $b$ with $a^2$ and $b^2$ in the above equations.

Comment: $f(a+b)f(0)=f(a+b)$ if and only if $f(0)=1$. This condition ($f(0)=1$) must be satisfied, otherwise you will not have your desired conclusion $f(a)f(b)=f(a+b)$.

Comment: If $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ then $f(a)f(b)=e^{-a^2}e^{-b^2}=e^{-a^2-b^2}$, but $f(a+b)=e^{-(a+b)^2}=e^{-a^2-2ab-b^2}\neq f(a)f(b)$.